# Python> How to: back from end second "while True" to first "while True"?

Tags: python

I wrote simple while loop to my Orange PI win to steering 5 LEDs and I don't know how to back from first loop while true.
Right now after second loop program is ending I would like to back for first loop

Could you advise how to do that?

```
import os
import time
os.system("echo 37 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio37/direction,echo 38 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/direction,echo 39 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio39/direction,echo 101 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio101/direction,echo 36 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio36/direction")

#zmienne
sl ="sleep 0.5"
i = 1
imax = 10
y = 0.2
z = 0.1
val = 10 
value = 1

L1_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio37/value"
L1_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio37/value"
L2_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value"
L2_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value"
L3_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio39/value"
L3_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio39/value"
L4_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio101/value"
L4_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio101/value"
L5_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio36/value"
L5_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio36/value"


timeout = time.time() + 5 # 5 seconds   
while True: 

    print ("2 prog", i)
    os.system(L1_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L1_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L2_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L2_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L3_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L3_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L4_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L4_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L5_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L5_Off)
    #time.sleep(y)
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
        continue
#right follow
timeout = time.time() + 5 # 5 seconds   
while True: 

    print ("2 prog", i)
    os.system(L5_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L5_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L4_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L4_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L3_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L3_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L2_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L2_Off)
    #time.sleep (y)
    os.system(L1_On)
    time.sleep (z)
    os.system(L1_Off)
    #time.sleep(y)
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
        continue
```

Comment: please read about a [mre]. also, your `continue` lines are not necessary as they are never seen because they come after a `break`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting both loops in another `while True:` loop, ie:

```
import os
import time
os.system("echo 37 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio37/direction,echo 38 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/direction,echo 39 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio39/direction,echo 101 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio101/direction,echo 36 > /sys/class/gpio/export,echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio36/direction")

#zmienne
sl ="sleep 0.5"
i = 1
imax = 10
y = 0.2
z = 0.1
val = 10 
value = 1

L1_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio37/value"
L1_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio37/value"
L2_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value"
L2_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value"
L3_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio39/value"
L3_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio39/value"
L4_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio101/value"
L4_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio101/value"
L5_On = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio36/value"
L5_Off = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio36/value"


while True:
    timeout = time.time() + 5 # 5 seconds   
    while True: 

        print ("2 prog", i)
        os.system(L1_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L1_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L2_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L2_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L3_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L3_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L4_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L4_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L5_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L5_Off)
        #time.sleep(y)
        if time.time() > timeout:
            break
            continue
    #right follow
    timeout = time.time() + 5 # 5 seconds   
    while True: 

        print ("2 prog", i)
        os.system(L5_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L5_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L4_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L4_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L3_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L3_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L2_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L2_Off)
        #time.sleep (y)
        os.system(L1_On)
        time.sleep (z)
        os.system(L1_Off)
        #time.sleep(y)
        if time.time() > timeout:
            break
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is a simple program, but I thought I could help reduce the redundancies in your code:

```
import os
import time

#zmienne
dir = 5
i = 1
y = 0.2
z = 0.1
path = "/sys/class/gpio/"
lights = [37, 38, 39, 101, 36]

def initialize():
    cmds = []
    for light in lights:
      cmds.append("echo %d > %sexport" % (light, path))
      cmds.append("echo out > %sgpio%d/direction" % (path, light))
    os.system(", ".join(cmds))

def flash(light, on=z):
    os.system("echo 1 > %sgpio%d/value" % (path, lights[light]))
    time.sleep(on)
    os.system("echo 0 > %sgpio%d/value" % (path, lights[light]))

initialize()
while True:
    #left follow
    timeout = time.time() + dir
    while time.time() < timeout:
        print ("1 prog", i)
        for l in range(len(lights)):
            flash(l)
            #time.sleep(y)
            if time.time() > timeout:
                break
    #right follow
    timeout = time.time() + dir
    while time.time() < timeout:
        print ("2 prog", i)
        for l in range(len(lights) - 1, -1, -1):
            flash(l)
            #time.sleep(y)
            if time.time() > timeout:
                break
```

- Extracted major gpio path if it ever changes (based on system/os)
- Created `lights` mapping for your code to iterate through (can also be adjusted in a single spot if you change up your pins, or order)
- Initialization method handles all the lights
- Flash method turns a single led on and off for a specific duration (current defaults to `z` seconds)
- Outer `while` loop ensures code runs forever
- Inner loops run lights for a specific time (`dir = 5` seconds) before switching directions, also stops if in the middle of a run

I hope this helps you out!